# icon fonts with opacity are cropped in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have discovered this bug in chrome with the icomoon font icons and i can't find a fix anywhere. When i add opacity to the icon,on chrome browser it looks cropped ( [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX7j6.png) ) , but when i remove the opacity is not cropped anymore ( [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZU7t.png) ) .Any fix ? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<div class="myicon">
<a class="icon-block"></a>
</div
```

CSS:

```
.myicon a {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

EDIT: I have replaced the **opacity: 0.6;** with **color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);** and is ok now.

Comment: We can't diagnose an image...we'd need a demo with the actual font.